# Running a script every time a new kernel is installed

Tags: kernel, kernel-modules

I'm currently having to recompile my wireless driver from source every time I get a new kernel release. Thinking it would be awesomely hackerish to automate this process, I symlinked my Bash build script to `/etc/kernel/postinst.d`. I've verified that it does, in fact, run when the latest kernel update is installed, but one thing is left as a problem: the driver compiles for the existing running version of the kernel.

For example, if I'm running 3.0.0-14-generic and `apt-get dist-upgrade` to kernel 3.0.0-15-generic, then it compiles for kernel 3.0.0-14-generic, which doesn't really help me at all.

Is there a way to tell from my kernel postinst script which version of the kernel has been installed so I can pass it to my `make` call so it can be compiled for the newly installed kernel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is no actual answer to your question, just a pointer to a tool that might be related and helpful:

---

Do you have [`dkms`](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=dkms) installed? ([Some information here](http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/os-applications/w/wiki/linux-projects.aspx), the [alioth page](http://pkg-dkms.alioth.debian.org/) seems down at the moment.) It's supposed to do just that, if I'm not misled.  It **requires** the appropriate `linux-headers` package and the module/firmware/something-like-that package to be installed; and it works for *all installed `linux-image` packages.* (I can't say anything about a generic module, but it worked fine when I used it with the non-free nvidia module.)

([There're more links here](http://linux.dell.com/dkms/), like [the manpage](http://linux.dell.com/dkms/manpage.html) and [this `linuxjournal.com` article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6896?page=0,1) which provides a non-Debian-ecosystem-centric explanation of the program.)

Comment: No, I think dkms *is* the answer.

Comment: I think so, too (DKMS is it). You have to put it into auto-rebuild mode for the driver in the dkms.conf.

Comment: How can I hook my script into it? There are a couple of different libraries which need to be installed, and both currently live in `/opt`.

Comment: In /usr/share/doc/dkms/ there are docs as well as examples. Start by looking through the example dkms.conf files and then ask a followup question if you have any  problems

Answer (score 2):

Although `dkms` may be the answer, I have an approach for you that may offer a solution that is simpler if you don't want to get involved with that or other complicated solutions.

Since you won't really need this until you do the reboot and begin running the new kernel anyway, why not just run the script just in time (on the next boot)?

You could use something self-contained like [this](https://serverfault.com/a/149803/128678) for queueing your command to run on the next boot only, and script *that* from `/etc/kernel/postinst.d`.

Answer (score 0):

dkms is indeed the answer if you're running a DKMS-enabled distro (like most of the popular ones). If you're running a distribution that doesn't use DKMS or you've spun your own Linux installation, read on.

The problem is that the `postinst.d` hook is called before the reboot, where `uname` still returns the old kernel version.

The solution is somewhat hackish but given that the entire matter revolves around a hack to prebuild modules after an upgrade, I'm sure that's ok :)

You just need to enumerate the files in `/boot/` (unless you're running some extremely esoteric setup where the kernel is installed somewhere else), sort the contents by mdate, and extract the kernel version from the most recently installed kernel, along these lines:

```bsh
KVERSION=$(ls -at /boot | sed -n 's/^vmlinuz-//;t p;b;:p;p;q')
# KVERSION will hold some value like 4.19.0-10-arm64
```

(This assumes kernel is compressed and installed as `/boot/vmlinuz-${KVERSION}`)

Comment: It's not clear whether the wifi driver installer would be able to do the right thing off of simply having the new `$KVERSION` set.

Comment: @StevenLu this isn’t for use with a binary installer, it’s for use with an installer that builds drivers from source including headers and linking against the kernel based off a path that is derived from the version string.

Answer (score 0):

The version of the new installed/reinstalled kernel is passed to all postinst.d scripts, or at least this is the case with Fedora and Redhat and their derivatives. And you read that value as you read the fist passed argument to a normal script in bash:

```bash
kernel_ver = ${1}
...
```

and the passed value is the same as what you get from running `uname -r`

I have just tested it and the passed value is `6.6.9-200.fc39.x86_64` which I use to compile drivers.