# What directory houses the scripts that get executed with new kernel installations?

Tags: linux, kernel, vmware

This one is pretty much a straightfoward question/answer I just can't locate the information.

I'm trying to automate the re-installation of VMWare tools based off when a new kernel is installed. I seem to remember there being a directory somewhere underneath `/etc` and whenever `new-kernel-pkg` installs a new kernel and goes to build the initrd it will execute any executable scripts it finds in there. I looked through my history and have tried to locate it on my system and via google but I can't find it.

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30320/running-a-script-every-time-a-new-kernel-is-installed)? However, `/etc/kernel/postinst.d` seems to be not present in RHEL.

Comment: Also, I found [this](http://vmadmin.nt.com.au/?p=52) one which says about some automated re-installation of VMWare tools.

Comment: @Ramesh, can you post both as an answer so I can accept it? I'm going to remove the rhel tag so it's generic to all distros.

Comment: It looks like the `dkms` package is mentioned a lot in relation to the `postinst.d` directory. Is that the package that handles the post-install actions? I installed it via epel and it didn't pull anything else in so I would assume that means `/etc/kernel/postinst.d` is operated by the `dkms` package itself.

Comment: But to answer your question, yes this is exactly what I was thinking of, I'm just trying to think of a way to get it to suit my purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30320/running-a-script-every-time-a-new-kernel-is-installed), I see that `/etc/kernel/postinst.d` is the place where scripts are placed when they need to be executed during the kernel installation time. This requires that [DKMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Kernel_Module_Support) is available on your system (many distributions, including RHEL, support it).

Since you had mentioned automating the re-installation of **VMWare** tools, I see that you could automate it as discussed [here](http://vmadmin.nt.com.au/?p=52).

The link has this below script.

```
#! /bin/bash
# Following lines auto-recompile VM Tools when kernel updated
 VMToolsCheckFile="/lib/modules/`uname -r`/misc/.vmware_installed"
 VMToolsVersion=`vmware-config-tools.pl --help 2>&1 | awk '$0 ~ /^VMware Tools [0-9]/ { print $3,$4 }'`

 printf "\nCurrent VM Tools version: $VMToolsVersion\n\n"

 if [[ ! -e $VMToolsCheckFile || `grep -c "$VMToolsVersion" $VMToolsCheckFile` -eq 0 ]]; then
 [ -x /usr/bin/vmware-config-tools.pl ] && \
 printf "Automatically compiling new build of VMware Tools\n\n" && \
 /usr/bin/vmware-config-tools.pl --default && \
 printf "$VMToolsVersion" > $VMToolsCheckFile && \
 rmmod pcnet32
 rmmod vmxnet
 depmod -a
 modprobe vmxnet
 fi
```

Save the above as file on your server called `vmware-check-tools`. Then do the following as root.

```
cp vmware-check-tools /etc/init.d
chmod 755 /etc/init.d/vmware-check-tools
cd /etc/rc.d/rc3.d
ln -s ../init.d/vmware-check-tools S09vmware-check-tools
```

However, I am not sure if that script does the job as required since I do not have a way to test it in my setup.